# ListFragment Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Hoje usando um Fragment para resolver um problema, vi que exite uma classe chamada de `ListFragment` mas o que ela faz? Qual a diferença com um `Fragment`?
Quando devo usar o `ListFragment` quando devo usar o `Fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

ListFragment é basicamente um Fragment com uma ListView. Tens alguns métodos como **getListView()** e **getListAdapter()** para te facilitar a vida.

Depende para o que precisas mas na maioria das vezes eu usaria um Fragment com Listview.

Fonte: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html